# Update YEAR data in values like YYYMM for column of Datatype numeric or nchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am struggling hard to update the YEAR data in some columns in the Database. The values are like 201201 (year+month). The datatype of this column (month_id) is numeric. I only need to change 201201 to 201501, 201301 to 201601 such that adding +3 to Year. 
I have tried using CAST, CONVERT. Tried to write queries as below:

```
UPDATE Table
SET month_id = SUBSTRING(CAST(month_id as VARCHAR(10)), 1, 4) +3 
WHERE month_id = '202011'
```

It gives result as 2023. Not 202311. Later I tried to CONCAT but it gives arithmetic error.
Can anyone please suggest a proper solution?

Also its same with another column day_desc (datatype - nchar [10]) and values are like 01.01.2012,01.01.2013, etc... Need to change years here as well. But since the data is in different format, I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
UPDATE Table
SET  month_id = month_id + 300
```

Comment: I think he wants to change all the years, I may be wrong though.

Comment: i am waiting the author reply after he tried this in production by CTRL+C and CTRL+V :-D

Comment: Tanner> Yes but that does not match with the examples given in the text of the question.  I suppose we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: I am still thinking what will happen after adding 300?

Comment: What usually happens when you add 300 to a number?  If you add 300 to the number 202011 what will the result be?

Comment: This worked as well.. Thank you. But in both the cases I have to provide all the old values one by one. I was trying to make it little more quick.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In these queries I have to write the values which needs to be changed in the where clause. So it would be each time a new value in WHERE clause. Any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
UPDATE Table
SET month_id = CONCAT( CAST(LEFT(month_id, 4) + 3 AS NVARCHAR(4)), RIGHT(month_id, 2))
WHERE month_id = '202011'
```

Edit based on your comment, with inputs like '01.01.2014':

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = CONCAT(LEFT(MyValue, 6), CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(MyValue, 4))+3)
WHERE MyColumn = '01.01.2014'
```

Edit2, based on your comments to other posts too:
if your target is to avoid multiple updates to same records, lets say you already updated `201401` to `201701` and you dont want your query make it `202001`, so you need to update some other column like `UPDATED BIT` where 1 = already updated, and 0 = not updated. 
More, be careful on where clause: do you really want to update ALL YOUR TABLE RECORDS with new logic (adding 3 years) or maybe you are looking only for some of them.

Comment: I also need to change years for values such as 01.01.2012,01.01.2013, etc.. Anything can you suggest on this please?

Comment: are those values datetime? or nvarchar? once you know data type, you can choose best functions to manipulate them.

Comment: That's nchar(10). But it cannot be converted to DATE as a datatype.

Answer (score 0):

This will work without you having to do any casting...

```
UPDATE Table
SET month_id = (((month_id / 100) + 3) * 100) + (month_id % 100)


--(month_id / 100) will return the year part
--(month_id % 100) will return the month part
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Can there be a solution where I need not to write the old values again and again? Something has to be  done with the where clause.